# How do I open a session using JSch, close that session, and then open a new one using the same credentials?

Tags: apache, groovy, integration-testing, jsch

I am having trouble with getting a session using JSch, closing that session, and then opening a new one with the same credentials some amount of time later. Would someone please take a look at my explanation below and offer any suggestions? Thank you very much.

I am unsure if my problem is with my test setup or my code, but the problem I am having is that I am unable to open, close, and then open a new ssh session using JSch with the same credentials. My test class contains two tests, both of which test the production code below:

```
def transferFiles(String filePath, Closure fileAction) {
    def secureChannel = new JSch()

    def session = secureChannel.getSession(sftpUser, sftpHost, sftpPort)
    session.setConfig('StrictHostKeyChecking', 'no')
    session.password = sftpPass
    session.connect()

    try {
        def sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel('sftp')
        sftpChannel.connect()
        try {
            processFiles(sftpChannel, filePath, fileAction)
        } finally {
            sftpChannel.exit()
        }
    } finally {
        session.disconnect()
    }
}
```

If I only run one test then it will always pass, but if I run the whole spec at once, then whichever test runs first will always pass and whichever test runs second will always fail with the following exception:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:349)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:215)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
at com.simplify.acquirer.evo.service.FileTransferringService.transferFiles(FileTransferringService.groovy:32)
at com.simplify.acquirer.evo.service.DepositService.processDeposits(DepositService.groovy:8)
at com.simplify.acquirer.evo.service.FileProcessingIntegrationSpec.Deposits are successfully processed(FileProcessingIntegrationSpec.groovy:127)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:343)
... 5 more
```

This is my test setup (with the then blocks removed from the tests since they should not be relevant):

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session
import com.jcraft.jsch.UserInfo
import org.apache.sshd.SshServer
import org.apache.sshd.server.Command
import org.apache.sshd.server.CommandFactory
import org.apache.sshd.server.PasswordAuthenticator
import org.apache.sshd.server.command.ScpCommandFactory
import org.apache.sshd.server.keyprovider.SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider
import org.apache.sshd.server.session.ServerSession
import org.apache.sshd.server.sftp.SftpSubsystem
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

class FileProcessingIntegrationSpec extends Specification {

@Shared
SshServer sshd

def setupSpec() {
    FileTransferringService.sftpUser = 'remote-username'
    FileTransferringService.sftpPass = 'remote-password'
    FileTransferringService.sftpHost = 'localhost'
    FileTransferringService.sftpPort = 22999

    sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer()
    sshd.port = FileTransferringService.sftpPort
    sshd.keyPairProvider = new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider('hostkey.ser')
    sshd.passwordAuthenticator = new PasswordAuthenticator() {
        public boolean authenticate(String username, String password, ServerSession session) {
            true
        }
    }
    sshd.commandFactory = new ScpCommandFactory(new CommandFactory() {
        public Command createCommand(String command) {
            System.out.println("Command: $command")
            null
        }
    })
    sshd.subsystemFactories = [new SftpSubsystem.Factory()]
    sshd.start()

    JSch sch = new JSch();
    Session session = sch.getSession("sshd", FileTransferringService.sftpHost, FileTransferringService.sftpPort);
    session.userInfo = new UserInfo() {
        public String getPassphrase() {
            null
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            'sshd'
        }

        public boolean promptPassword(String message) {
            true
        }

        public boolean promptPassphrase(String message) {
            false
        }

        public boolean promptYesNo(String message) {
            true
        }

        public void showMessage(String message) {
        }
    }
    session.connect()

    ChannelSftp c = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp")
    c.connect()
    c.put(new FileInputStream('src/integrationTest/resources/file1.xls'), 'file1.xls')
    c.put(new FileInputStream('src/integrationTest/resources/file2.csv'), 'file2.csv')
    c.disconnect()
}

def cleanup() {
    sshd.stop()
}

def "Files are successfully processed"() {
    when:
    def result = new FileProcessingService().processFile('file1.xls')

    then:
    ...
}

def "More files are successfully processed"() {
    when:
    def result = new FileProcessingService().processFile('file2.csv')

    then:
    ...
}
}
```

If more information is needed, I will strive to provide it as best as I can. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `cleanupSpec` instead of `cleanup`. The way your code works right now, the sshd server that you create in `setupSpec` is stopped after the first test, which explains why the second test subsequently fails.

This was probably just an oversight, but for completeness sake, here are the fixture method definitions:

```
def setup() {}         // run before every feature method
def cleanup() {}       // run after every feature method
def setupSpec() {}     // run before the first feature method
def cleanupSpec() {}   // run after the last feature method
```

Comment: You were absolutely correct! Thank you for pointing out my outrageous oversight! I would vote you up but I lack the reputation :(